# Inversion von Subjekt und Verb

Tags: word-order

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Verb inversion with adverbs used at the beginning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/612/verb-inversion-with-adverbs-used-at-the-beginning)

Warum vertauschen wir in einigen Sätzen das Subjekt mit dem Verb, wie:

> Gestern bin ich mit Lisa ...

(Das ist falsch: Gestern ich bin mit Lisa)

Answer (score 2):

Im Hauptsatz nimmt das flektierte Verb immer die **zweite** Position ein.

Häufig befindet sich das Subjekt in der ersten Position, dann liegt die Anordnung Subjekt-Verb vor:

> Ich bin gestern mit Lisa ...

Wenn aber das Adverb an die erste Stelle tritt, kann nicht als nächstes das Subjekt kommen, denn an der zweiten Position steht immer das Verb. Das Subjekt reiht sich dann als drittes ein, wodurch die Anordnung Adverb-Verb-Subjekt entsteht:

> Gestern bin ich mit Lisa ...

Answer (score 1):

Das **Prädikat** (Verb) steht in deutschen Aussagesätzen immer an **zweiter Stelle**. Somit muss das Subjekt hinter das Prädikat gestellt werden.

Im Beispiel der Frage handelt es sich um ein mehrteiliges Prädikat

> Gestern **bin** ich mit Lisa **im Kino gewesen**.

Die Regel gilt aber auch für einteilige Prädikate:

> Vorgestern **war** ich im Zoo.