# Adverb at the start of a sentence

Tags: meaning, adverb, word-order

I am currently attempting to read 'Wir Kinder vom Bahnhof Zoo' as it was recommended by my teacher as being an easy read. However, on the first page I have found something confusing.

The sentence in question is

> Wahrscheinlich, weil ich zunächst einen
>   urischen Horror vor dieser Wohnung hatte

After some googling, I found [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/617/5642) German stackexchange question.  In this answer it is clearly stated that "*If you place an adverb (or an adverbial phrase) at the beginning of the sentence, then the predicate (verb) must come next*". So why, in this sentence is the adverb "Wahrscheinlich" followed by weil? And also, the answer linked above states, "*adverbial phrases are not separated from the rest of the clause by a comma when put at the beginning of the sentence.*". So again, I do not see why this Wahrsheinlich is any different? All I can think is that it is part of something that I am failing to spot however it is it's own sentence so I cannot see how what is before it matters. However, if this could make a difference then here is the sentence in context:

> Wie die Wohnung aussah, in die wir dann kamen, habe ich
>   auch nie vergessen. Wahrscheinlich, weil ich zunächst einen
>   urischen Horror vor dieser Wohnung hatte. Sie war so groß
>   und leer, daß ich Angst hatte, mich zu verlaufen. Wenn man
>   laut sprach, hallte es unheimlich.

*Note* As a side question, what is the meaning of 'urischen'? I have tried [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/) and google translate and neither have a meaning for it.

Any help is much appreciated, as this has really made me wonder if this is an easy read or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is rather simple.The sentence in the example isn't actually a real sentence in that there is no main sentence. It is a shortened version of this:

> Wahrscheinlich habe ich die Wohnung nie vergessen, weil...

or this

> Wahrscheinlich war das (was ich im Satz davor gesagt habe) der Fall, weil...

As for "urischen Horror"... look for Urangst. That should make it clearer. It's a primal horror, but "urisch" is not really a word and I only understood it in combination with horror.

Comment: Thank you for clearing up the meaning of urisch. And also thank you for explaining the fact it wasn't a real sentence. It makes much more sense now!

Comment: Well, very strictly spoken, it *is* a real sentence, where "Wahrscheinlich," is the main clause - in a very reduced manner.